# NSTimer timeInterval parameter doesn't allow variable

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

When I use

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.75, target: self, selector: Selector("drawInTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

it works fine but if I want to use a variable (instead of 0.75) for the timeInterval parameter

```
var waitTime = CGFloat(numberOMiliseconds) / 1000.0
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval: waitTime, target: self, selector: Selector("drawInTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

or

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(waitTime, target: self, selector: Selector("drawInTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

then I get the following error "Swift compiler error: Extra argument 'selector' in call".
Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` signature:

```
class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti: NSTimeInterval, target aTarget: AnyObject, selector aSelector: Selector, userInfo: AnyObject?, repeats yesOrNo: Bool) -> NSTimer
```

you notice that the method doesn't have an external name for the first parameter (that's default for methods), so you don't have to use the `timeInterval` external name.

Moreover, its expected type is `NSTimeInterval`, which is a typealias for `Double`, but you are passing a `CGFloat`.

So you should change your code to:

```
var waitTime = Double(numberOMiliseconds) / 1000.0
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(waitTime, target: self, selector: Selector("drawInTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works! It was easy but the error message was not adapted, it should be something like "Wrong type in argument!"

Comment: I agree with that - but I think it happens the compiler tries to map your call to one of the several overloads for which there's no expected parameter having the `selector` external name.